# Create Array of Unique Values from ColA where Col B are the same in Sql.DataFrame

Tags: sql, dataframe, scala, apache-spark

I have a `sql.DataFrame`:

```
ID | Qualifier
-------------
A  |    "test"
A  |    "test2"
```

And I would like to get to:

```
ID | QualifierList
-------------
A  |    ["test", "test2"]
```

Using spark `sql` functions.

I can't seem to find any way with `array_join()` etc. Any help would be appreciated!

The datasource I'm using is much larger than this, but when I try `array_join()` I get the values that exist in the `Qualifier` column, but not the values where `ID` are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `groupBy` function, followed by the `collect_list` aggregation function. Something like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import spark.implicits._

val df = Seq(
  ("A", "test"),
  ("A", "test2")
).toDF("ID", "Qualifier")

val output = df.groupBy("ID").agg(collect_list("Qualifier").alias("QualifiersList"))

output.show
+---+--------------+                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
| ID|QualifiersList|                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
+---+--------------+                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
|  A| [test, test2]|                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
+---+--------------+
```